# Error message: Sequence contains no elements

Tags: petapoco

I am using `Connection.db.Single<Test>("select * from Test WHERE ID= " + id)` for a test as follows:

```
Assert.IsNull(Connection.db.Single<Test>("select * from Test WHERE ID= " + id));
```

I know that the resultset should be a null as there is no row for  the value of id I am passing.  However, an error is fired as follows:

Sequence contains no elements and exception details is as follows: System.InvalidOperationException was unhandled by user code
  Message=Sequence contains no elements
  Source=System.Core
  StackTrace:
       at System.Linq.Enumerable.Single[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
       at PetaPoco.Database.Single[T](String sql, Object[] args) in C:\Dev\Models\PetaPoco.cs:line 1120

1. Can`t I use Single to test null?
2. Is there a better method to test the Asset.IsNUll ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
Assert.IsNull(Connection.db.SingleOrDefault<Test>("select * from Test WHERE ID= " + id));
```

Answer (score 0):

use Any() or FirstOrDefault, as in:

```
if ( context.Product.Any( x => x.ProductId == 1 ) ) ...
```

Comment: I'm using .Any() but still getting the error (AttendantTrackingSD is a bool): return chatUserRepository.Table.Where(c => c.AttendantTrackingSD).Any();